# Retrofit response.errorBody cannot be converted to JsonObject or Java Obejct

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2.6

When the API is called it return an object in onScuccess with status code 201 and when not in onSuccess along with status code 422 it also gives an object like this

```
{
    "errors": [
         "Usuário não encontrado"
    ]
}
```

I have tried many ways including from retrofit official website which uses this code

```
public class ErrorUtils {


public static APIError parseError(Response<JsonObject> response) {

    Converter<ResponseBody, APIError> converter =
            ServiceGenerator.retrofit()
                    .responseBodyConverter(APIError.class, new Annotation[0]);

    APIError error;

    try {
        error = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v("LoginUser", "IOException -> " + e.getMessage());
        return new APIError();
    }

    return error;
}

public static class ServiceGenerator {
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = ApiClient.BASE_URL;

    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static Retrofit retrofit() {
        retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}}
```

API Error Class

```
public class APIError {
private String[] errors;

public String[] getErrors() {
    return errors;
}

public void setErrors(String[] errors) {
    this.errors = errors;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "ClassPojo [errors = " + errors + "]";
}}
```

But in this way it goes into catch block of Error Utils class and the exception is

```
End of input at line 1 column 1 path $
```

Solution for this issue will be much appreciated. But keep this in mind that I have looked thoroughly on SO for both of these errors, then I post this question.

Comment: Did you tried `String[]` to `ArrayList<String>` in `APIError` class?

Comment: Its the same 
End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Check what are you getting in response.errorBody() & response.getBody()

Comment: `@SerializedName("errors")` `@Expose` add this in `APIError` class above to `private String[] errors`

Comment: @MUHAMMADHUMZAKhan its a login api, If enter wrong credentials then response goes into response.errorBody() 422. it contains an object which i pasted above. When result is response.isSuccess then it has an object with user data

Comment: @FaizanKhan things will be fine if you are getting mentioned response, but i don't think so. Check value of response.errorBody() using debugger.

Comment: @MuhammadAwais Unfortunately error is still same

Comment: @MUHAMMADHUMZAKhan Here is the result of debugger https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VnO8R603M9_QiBNUQt4GGcx8ZUoleNm8/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @FaizanKhan can you share the API Endpoint along with request ?

Comment: @MUHAMMADHUMZAKhan
https://staging.api.mappa-concursos.jera.com.br/v1/users/sign_in
pass this in body
email:andymandy@gmail.com
password:123456

Comment: Getting 401 (Unauthorized) on execution API on Postman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225157/discussion-between-faizan-khan-and-muhammad-humza-khan).

Comment: Waiting on chat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try this code in your `onResponse` Callback Method*

```
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.code() == 201) {

                      // Todo

                } else {

                    if (response.errorBody() != null) {

                        try {

                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.errorBody().string());

                            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("errors");

                            List<String> errorStringList = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                                errorStringList.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());

                            }


                        } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }

                }
```

*You can pass `errorStringList` to the instance of your `ApiError`*

```
ApiError apiError = new ApiError();

apiError.setError(errorStringList.toArray(new String[0]))
```